# AMP Connection with inactive site

Tags: amp-html, google-search-console

sorry for my bad english.

i want to ask something, so AMPHTML allow that amp page direct to other domain right? how can i disconnect that AMP from the main domain that already inactive?

**Note: im not the owner of that domain, because this domain is violating rules and also law in spesific Country (Indonesia)

i just want to know is there any way to force disconnect that inactive AMP to the illegal page on google SERPS.

last time, i tried to remove the content from Google feature "Remove Outdated Content" but the user that doing this illegal things is still have access to the Google Search Console of that website even the website is now inactive.

I hope someone here or all the community can help me to know what should i do when face this problem, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.